# py.test to test Cython C API modules

Tags: unit-testing, cython, pytest

I'm trying to set up unit tests for a Cython module to test some functions that do not have python interface. The first idea was to check if `.pyx` files could directly be used by `py.test`'s test runner, but apparently it only scans for `.py` files.

Second idea was to write the `test_*` methods in one Cython module, which could then be imported into a plain `.py` file. Let say we have a `foo.pyx` module with the contents we want to test:

```
cdef int is_true():
    return False
```

then a `test_foo.pyx` module that uses the C API to test the `foo` module:

```
cimport foo

def test_foo():
    assert foo.is_true()
```

and then import these in a plain `cython_test.py` module that would just contain this line:

```
from foo_test import *
```

The `py.test` test runner does find `test_foo` this way, but then reports:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py:752: in getargs
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a code object'.format(co))
E   TypeError: <built-in function test_foo> is not a code object
```

Is there any better way to test Cython C-API code using `py.test`?

Comment: Just a quick note: I've found a hacky way of doing so, but I need some time to document it.

Comment: Take a look at [pytest-cpp](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cpp) to get some ideas on how to write a plugin that can run tests directly from `.pyx` files.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira: you might be interested in the solution I posted below. Cython-compiled modules aren't that different from pure Python ones, so I settled on a short-term hack that I hope won't be necessary with slight adjustments in future versions of Python (so that `inspect.getargspec` worked with user-defined types), Cython (to implement `inspect.getargspec` and get rid of its internal `__test__` attribute) and maybe py.test (to adjust some asserts).

Answer (score 6):

So, in the end, I managed to get `py.test` to run tests directly from a Cython-compiled `.pyx` files. However, the approach is a terrible hack devised to make use of `py.test` Python test runner as much as possible. It might stop working with any `py.test` version different from the one I prepared the hack to work with (which is 2.7.2).

First thing was to defeat `py.test`'s focus on `.py` files. Initially, `py.test` refused to import anything that didn't have a file with `.py` extension. Additional problem was that `py.test` verifies whether the module's `__FILE__` matches the location of the `.py` file. Cython's `__FILE__` generally does not contain the name of the source file though. I had to override this check. I don't know if this override breaks anything—all I can say is that the tests seem to run well, but if you're worried, please consult your local `py.test` developer. This part was implemented as a local `conftest.py` file.

```
import _pytest
import importlib


class Module(_pytest.python.Module):
    # Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250450/
    def _importtestmodule(self):
        # Copy-paste from py.test, edited to avoid throwing ImportMismatchError.
        # Defensive programming in py.test tries to ensure the module's __file__
        # matches the location of the source code. Cython's __file__ is
        # different.
        # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/2.7.2/_pytest/python.py#L485
        path = self.fspath
        pypkgpath = path.pypkgpath()
        modname = '.'.join(
            [pypkgpath.basename] +
            path.new(ext='').relto(pypkgpath).split(path.sep))
        mod = importlib.import_module(modname)
        self.config.pluginmanager.consider_module(mod)
        return mod

    def collect(self):
        # Defeat defensive programming.
        # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/2.7.2/_pytest/python.py#L286
        assert self.name.endswith('.pyx')
        self.name = self.name[:-1]
        return super(Module, self).collect()


def pytest_collect_file(parent, path):
    # py.test by default limits all test discovery to .py files.
    # I should probably have introduced a new setting for .pyx paths to match,
    # for simplicity I am hard-coding a single path.
    if path.fnmatch('*_test.pyx'):
        return Module(path, parent)
```

Second major problem is that `py.test` uses Python's `inspect` module to check names of function arguments of unit tests. Remember that `py.test` does that to inject fixtures, which is a pretty nifty feature, worth preserving. `inspect` does not work with Cython, and in general there seems to be no easy way to make original `inspect` to work with Cython. Nor there is any other good way to inspect Cython function's list of arguments. For now I decided to make a small workaround where I'm wrapping all test functions in a pure Python function with desired signature.

In addition to that, it seems that Cython automatically puts a `__test__` attribute to each `.pyx` module. The way Cython does that interferes with `py.test`, and needed to be fixed. As far as I know, `__test__` is an internal detail of Cython not exposed anywhere, so it should not matter that we're overwriting it. In my case, I put the following function into a `.pxi` file for inclusion in any `*_test.pyx` file:

```
from functools import wraps


# For https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/2.7.2/_pytest/python.py#L340
# Apparently Cython injects its own __test__ attribute that's {} by default.
# bool({}) == False, and py.test thinks the developer doesn't want to run
# tests from this module.
__test__ = True


def cython_test(signature=""):
    ''' Wrap a Cython test function in a pure Python call, so that py.test
    can inspect its argument list and run the test properly.

    Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250450/'''
    if isinstance(signature, basestring):
        code = "lambda {signature}: func({signature})".format(
            signature=signature)

        def decorator(func):
            return wraps(func)(eval(code, {'func': func}, {}))

        return decorator

    # case when cython_test was used as a decorator directly, getting
    # a function passed as `signature`
    return cython_test()(signature)
```

After that, I could implement tests like:

```
include "cython_test_helpers.pxi"
from pytest import fixture

cdef returns_true():
    return False

@cython_test
def test_returns_true():
    assert returns_true() == True

@fixture
def fixture_of_true():
    return True

@cython_test('fixture_of_true')
def test_fixture(fixture_of_true):
    return fixture_of_true == True
```

If you decide to use the hack described above, please remember to leave yourself a comment with a link to this answer—I'll try to keep it updated in case better solutions are available.

Comment: I've covered some of this in a new pytest-plugin (still very early phase). It becomes a lot easier to work with, if you set the `binding` compiler directive for `cythonize`: https://github.com/Baekalfen/pytest-cython-collect